# Show all Einstein Activities for users that left the company?

Tags: einstein, einstein-activity-capture

We have Einstein Activity Capture on, and it works.

Our settings are 'Shared to All'.  (Note: even with this setting, Einstein still hides certain emails, based on it's own AI)

We have users that have left the company, and now we want to see their email (mainly the hidden one)

- we can login, and share each and every activity - but this is definitly not the right approach nor the solution.

Is there a way to modify that? so when selecting, ALL activities will be open and shared? Even those that the Einstein engine decided to hide?

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, as an overall policy, Admin can setup default sharing model for Activity capture and prevent users from modifying it.  This is a consideration, going forward, in case it is not in place.   Additionally, you may plan to apply certain sharing policies for the users that are serving the notice period (exit-phase), to ensure all available activities are exposed.

With regards to exposing the hidden ones, it is being done by design, only to be used for Machine Learning purposes.  Certain Sales Cloud Einstein features (e.g. Opportunity insights) use those private emails.

With respect to your comment on "we can login and share each activity", do you mean logging on-behalf of the users that have left the company?   I would not recommend this approach, instead would try to adopt the policy as noted in the 1st paragraph.

I would also be curious to know the purpose behind this... If the intention is to do a forensic analysis, there may be other ways to handle it.  But, if the intention is on whether Einstein would be able to use these activities, yes - it does, even when the user is inactive/frozen.

Lastly, there is no way, I could come across, to extract those hidden messages - this may require a case to be raised w Salesforce to find a solution or work-around.

Regards,
Kannan